# Makefile processing files with same extension

Tags: makefile

This seems slightly related to [How to write Makefile where target and source files have the same extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037581/how-to-write-makefile-where-target-and-source-files-have-the-same-extension).  In that question the extensions are the same, but the input and output files seem to be in the same directory and filenames are being conditionally renamed.

I have a large collection of `.txt` files in `../src/` that need to be processed, and dumped into `./` (which is a directory called `target/`) as txt files of the same name.  I want to use `make`, so that only files in `../src/` that have been changed get updated in `./`.  I would like to get the prototype working before I put the real code in.

My `Makefile` in `./` is as follows:

```
DIR = ../src
INPUTS = $(wildcard $(DIR)/*.txt)
OUTPUTS = $(patsubst $(DIR)/%.txt,%.txt,$(INPUTS))

all: $(OUTPUTS)

.PHONY: $(INPUTS)

check:
    @echo "DIR = $(DIR)"
    @echo "INPUTS = $(INPUTS)"
    @echo "OUTPUTS = $(OUTPUTS)"

%.txt: $(DIR)/%.txt
    sed -e "s/test/cat/g" "$<" > $@
```

For now, the contents of `../src/` are `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`.
As the Makefile stands now, running `make test2.txt` generates the file as expected.

```
target/ $ make test2.txt
sed -e "s/test/cat/g" "../src/test2.txt" > test2.txt
```

Running `make check` shows the `INPUTS` and `OUTPUTS` correctly.

```
target/ $ make check
DIR = ../src
INPUTS = ../src/test1.txt ../src/test2.txt
OUTPUTS = test1.txt test2.txt
```

If I run `make all`, it generates every file, every time.  This is expected with the `.PHONY $(INPUTS)` line in there.

If I remove the `.PHONY $(INPUTS)` target, Make gets all bound up in itself trying to find the target to make `../src/test1.txt` and keeps prefixing `$(DIR)` in front of it until it makes too long of a filename and gives up.

```
make: stat: ../src/../src/../src/ [repeat for a few pages] ../src/../src/test1.txt: File name too long
make: stat: ../src/../src/../src/ [repeat for a few pages] ../src/../src/../src/test1.txt: File name too long
make: *** No rule to make target `../src/../src/../src/[repeat]../src/../src/test1.txt', needed by `../src/[repeat]../src/../src/test1.txt'.  Stop.
```

It never does get to processing `test2.txt`.

---

As I was drafting this, I had the idea to remove the `../` from the DIR,
and relocate the Makefile so it was parent to both `src/` and `target/`.  That approach seems to work, but isn't ideal.  Eventually there would be a chain of these Makefiles, each pulling from one directory to another.

Is there a way to keep the `Makefile` in 'target/' along with the generated destination files, and base those destination files off of something in a relative path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
%.txt: $(DIR)/%.txt
```

with:

```
${CURDIR}/%.txt: $(DIR)/%.txt
```

This way `%.txt` does not match any `.txt` file in any directory. In other words, you limit this rule's scope to files in `${CURDIR}/` only and this prevents that endless recursion.

See [§10.5.4 How Patterns Match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) for more details.

It is also good practice to avoid relative paths:

```
DIR = $(abspath ../src)
```

Comment: Perfect.  I had to alter the `OUTPUTS = ...` line to be `OUTPUTS = $(patsubst $(DIR)/%.txt,${CURDIR}/%.txt,$(INPUTS))`, but worked as advertised.  Thank you!

Comment: @MattD. Good, `make` is a bit too sensitive to paths, it does string filename comparison only, e.g. "../src/x" is not equal "../src/../src/x".

Comment: @MattD. This is why converting all paths to absolute helps avoid this issue.